# Get device name in C programming [Linux]

Tags: c, linux

This question may be to broad. However, one accepted answer is good enough.

Any clever way of obtaining device name (`/dev/input/`)?
At the moment this is what I'm doing:

```
char name[256] = "Unknown";
char *device = "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd";

// Open device & get file descriptor
if ((fd = open (device, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1)
{
    ...
}

// Get device name
ioctl (fd, EVIOCGNAME (sizeof (name)), name);
```

Is there a more direct way of obtaining the device name? I'd like to skip the part where I have to open the file in order to obtain device name.

The reason is because I'm going through all devices within that folder to find a matching device name.

Maybe something similar to this (Python) but in C ofcourse:

```
from evdev import InputDevice,list_devices

devices = map(InputDevice, list_devices())

for dev in devices:
    print dev.fn+" - "+dev.name
    if "SomeDevicaName" in dev.name:
        infile_path = dev.fn
```

Comment: How would you know which device name to retrieve if you don't supply its file descriptor?

Comment: For instance, I have a given name that I'd like to find a match to. Thus I loop through all the names within "/dev/input/by-id/". I thought that there is a command that has the ability to retrieve the device name directly. So I could skip the step where I have to open the file, get name, close file. Maybe I'm being to lazy right now. But in python, there is such a function :P

Comment: @ezFreak What function is this in Python? Which module?

Comment: I just mentioned that I saw a short way of doing this in python. This is C. Sorry, but what do u mean by module?

Comment: It won't prevent opening a file, but could lead to skipping the `ioctl` part. Perhaps you can try browsing through `sys/class/input`, I've seen the name exported as a file there.

Comment: @Quentin See my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan I'll see what I can find in there. Thanks

Comment: You can find the name for a given input device in `/sys/class/input/event<N>/device/name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to get it is by reading `/proc/bus/input/devices` and parsing it out of the Name field.

For example, my input device of concern shows up as follows.

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0100
N: Name="gpio-keys"
P: Phys=gpio-keys/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/gpio-keys/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=300000 0 0 78000000 0
```

Then I can match it on the name to avoid iterating and opening each input device. Granted, this is a TOCTOU race that could occur if your input devices are quickly being added and removed; the name should still be checked using ioctl after opening the device.

[This answer on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74907/61232) does a great job explaining the other elements.